# Python npzFile objects are very slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am working with data and my code is working extremely slow for some reason.

Consider the following example, where I generate and save `data` object that consists of 200 arrays of variable length (5000-20000):

```
import time, numpy as np


array_lengths=np.random.randint(5000,20000,200)
data=np.empty(200,dtype=np.ndarray)
for ind,i in enumerate(array_lengths):
    data[ind]=np.random.randn(i)        

np.savez('data.npz',data)
```

This procedure takes fractions of seconds (0.25 s), as arrays are not too large.

Now I simply want to load this data object and calculate the length of each array in it.

```
start = time.time()
data=np.load('data.npz')
lengths=np.zeros(200)
for i in range(200):
    lengths[i]=len(data['arr_0'][i])
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

This extremely simple operation takes 32 seconds!

I am confused, why does it take so long.

Thanks,

Mikhail

Comment: Your `savez` created one `npy` file, not 200.   So you only need to access it once: `data = data['arr_0']`.  The shape of all component arrays is then `[len(i) for i in data]`.  Instead you load the same `data['arr_0']` 200 times!

Comment: Perhaps you wanted instead to use `np.savez('data.npz', *data)`.  Now look at its keys. Though even with that fetching the array lengths shouldn't take much longer: `[len(data[i]) for i in data.keys()] `

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the comment. So, is that true that by calling `data['arr_0']` I load a file from the hard drive again and again? I thought npz file object is some kind of an associative container (e.g. dictionary)  and `['arr_0']` accesses a member of this container

Comment: The `load` fetches the archive info.  The `data['x']` reads the `npy` file.  It might help to use your `dos` file archive viewer.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks. You can post your answer itf you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the comments by hpaulj.

Use `data['arr_0']` outside the loop, otherwise the data is loaded 200 times.

Benchmarks:
Loading data outside the loop:

```
%%timeit    
start = time.time()
data=np.load('data.npz')['arr_0']
lengths=np.zeros(200)
for i in range(200):
    lengths[i]=len(data[i])
end = time.time()

10 loops, best of 5: 115 ms per loop
```

Loading data inside the loop:

```
%%time    
start = time.time()
data=np.load('data.npz')
lengths=np.zeros(200)
for i in range(200):
    lengths[i]=len(data['arr_0'][i])
end = time.time()

Wall time: 24 s
```